# File.exists() not reliable on android device?

Tags: android

Recently, I received several exception log thrown in code below:

```
if(apk != null && !apk.exists()) {
  throw new Exception("xxxxxx");
}
```

The apk file is downloaded from cdn server:

```
download(url, new Listener(){
  public void onSuccess(File tempFile) {
    File apk = getApkFile("apkName.apk");
    renameTo(tempFile, apk); // the apk is mentioned above
  }
});

public static boolean renameTo(File source, File dest) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096 * 2];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            FileUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
            FileUtils.closeQuietly(fos);
            return source.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
}

static File getApkFile(String name) {
        File dir = new File(ContextUtil.get().getFilesDir(), DIR_PLUGIN);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        return new File(dir, name);
}
```

But the count is not too many, about 40 in 400000+ devices, Is there anyone experiences this problem ?

Comment: ErrorLog please!=)

Comment: `if(apk != null && apk.exists()) {
  throw new Exception("xxxxxx");}` ????? Why would you throw an exception if a file exists? Impossible code.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, this is a mistake, I have correct the post.

Comment: It is unclear to me why you suggest that File.exists() in unreliable. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There are tree reasons for your problem. First you are not checking the return value of `renameTo()`. Second you do not inform the user/yourself if there is a catch in `renameTo()`. Third `mkdirs()` can fail. You are not checking the return value. If it returns false you continue with your code as if nothing had happened.

All in all not very robust code. And then running on 400000 devices...

Comment: the exception thrown will be caught, so this won't cause a crash, you should tell me in which case `renameTo()` and `mkdirs()` will return `false`

Comment: What if you applied the changes i suggested?